# Docker image Pull from Azure Machine Learning Service Workspace

Tags: azure, docker, docker-image

I created a docker image in `Azure Machine Learning Service Workspace`.
The image is successfully created.
What I need at the moment is to pull the image from that workspace to my local machine and run it locally using powershell.
When I pull an image from a container registry, it works fine.

I tried to pull it using this command:

```
docker pull myregistry.azurecr.io/myimage:v1.0.0
```

but I get this error message:

> "Error response from daemon: manifest for myregistry.azurecr.io/myimage:v1.0.0 not found"

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it means that there is no image which you want to pull in the registry. So you should check if the image is already in your registry. If exist, perhaps you use a wrong tag. If not, push the image to the registry, then you can pull the image locally.

Comment: The image exists in the workspace and tags are correct but  the image is created with python script using Jupyter Notebook, and it only exists in Azure Machine Learning Service Workspace.

Comment: @MahdiKhardani While you use the command `docker pull myregistry.azurecr.io/myimage:v1.0.0` to pull the image in the local, you need to push the image to the registry server `myregistry.azurecr.io` first. Do not just left the image in the Machine Learning.

Comment: the image is created using Jupyter Notebook following this tutorial [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where], I can obtain the image in the workspace and only in the workspace, is there a way to move/create it in the registry?

Comment: @MahdiKhardani You provide a bad link, please fix it.

Comment: Yes my bad, here is the new link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-deploy-and-where

Comment: @MahdiKhardani When you create the ML workspace, there is an Azure Container Registry added automatically. So you can check if the image that you created is in the ACR. If exists, you can pull the image in local from the ACR.

Comment: that is what I am trying to do but I couldn't find the image in the ACR, it only exists in the workspace.

Comment: @MahdiKhardani When you create the image in ML, do you set the workspace as Azure Container Registry that associated with the ML?

Comment: If I set the workspace name to the ACR, it gives an error: Workspce not found, it works only when I set the workspace name to the Machine Learning service workspace.

Comment: @MahdiKhardani You need to take a look at the [Model Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/concept-azure-machine-learning-architecture#model-registry). And see [the steps of deployment tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment).